# Why is UITableViewCell initialization not working inside initWithCoder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I'm trying to clean up my code and use MVC principles by pushing as much view related stuff as i can into the storyboard as well as custom UIView classes (ie as opposed to doing view related stuff on the `UIViewController` itself)

So I have a custom UITableViewCell (called `CustomCell`) that has several properties, one of them is my own `label`. Since I'm loading the cell from the storyboard, I initialize it with `initWithCoder` rather than `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`, this is what I have in `CustomCell.m` which is a subclass of `UITableViewCell` (for some reason i couldn't figure out how to set a custom font using storyboard.. but that's beside the point of this question):

```
// CustomCell.m - subclass of UITableViewCell
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"customizing cell font having text %@", self.label.text);
        UIFont *customFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Montserrat" size:16];
        self.label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [self.label setFont:customFont];
    }
    return self;
}
```

This simply doesn't work.. the log statement outputs `null` for the text simply b/c the text hasn't been loaded yet. `self.label` is also null (I don't know why I thought it should have been inflated from the nib by now) but even if I initialize it here.. it still won't work.

So my work around was to simply put this cell customization part here in the `TableViewController`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {        
    UIFont *customFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Montserrat" size:16];
    [((CustomCell *)cell).label setFont:customFont];
}
```

and it worked just fine.. I'm unhappy with this method and I would like to know how to make it work from within `CustomCell.m`

**update:** to make things even more interesting.. if i put customization code for UITableViewCell properties inside initWithCoder, they work! consider this example:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        [bgColorView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        [self setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];  // actually works!
    }
    return self;
}
```

which makes this even more weird.

Comment: maybe `initWithCoder:` method is on background thread. try excuse the code from another method with `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`

Comment: Use awakeFromNib to init your controls, I think this is the best function for that but it can be called multiple times.

Comment: @theShay my update shows that this has nothing to do with a background thread

Comment: So try `awakeFromNib` or `viewDidApper`

Comment: @theShay cells don't have `viewDidAppear:` method.

Comment: @andykkt awake from nib works! i'll update my own question with the answer.. if you answer i'll give the correct answer award :)

Comment: You just have to remember, when init function called, sub views are not exist yet. the are instantiated when the loadView method is called. so if you are working with view controller then use viewDidLoad, and if you are working with UIView then use awakeFromNib or didAddSubview.

Comment: @andykkt your comment about subviews existing yet or not is irrelevant.. because if it were the code above wouldn't work even for a cell background's view. It does. That's why it's more about the fact that the outlets haven't been set up yet than views been instantiated or not.  See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19674308/766570) below.

Comment: @abbood Yup, I think you are right about outlets it's just not connected yet.  however, bgColorView case is different because it's not a subview of the view that being called initWithCoder, you made separated view and changed the its property which means you are not changing the property of subview you changed the property of self.  as long as I know, initWithCoder called when it loading the Nib from the bundle and at this stage, all subviews are not yet instantiated, how can you instantiate subview without parent? note that initWithCoder returns self.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inspired by [andykkt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2113425/andykkt)'s comment, I found the explanation in [awakeFromNib](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSObject_UIKitAdditions/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/awakeFromNib) documentation:

> The nib-loading infrastructure sends an awakeFromNib message to each
>   object recreated from a nib archive, but only after all the objects in
>   the archive have been loaded and initialized. When an object receives
>   an awakeFromNib message, it is guaranteed to have all its outlet and
>   action connections already established.

so that explains the weird behaviour above: `initWithCoder` instantiates a standard `UITableViewCell` (that already comes pre-baked with a backgroundView etc etc).. however it still doesn't recognize the outlets I've added to it via storyboard.. `awakeFromNib` does.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `initWithCoder:` method doesn't draw the contents of the cell, it just, initialises the object, and as you have noticed, accessing any of the ui drawing methods of the cell actually 'draws' the cell to apply the changes you have made to the cell. You can see the same behaviour when initing `UIViewController`'s using `initWithNibName:bundle:` method.